# The complexity of member looking up: Python Vs. Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am curious about the complexity of Python and JS 's looking up:

Python supports multi-inheritance, which affects the member lookup. Specifically, when referencing a member from an instance of a class, the process will start from the instance's dict, then to the class of the instance, then up to the super classes of the class of the instance, which for each super class, it has its own super class list..... which seems to end up with the complexity to be exponential (theoretically).

While it seems that the JS's member lookup time is linear -- which just has to trace back to the prototype chain.

Am I reasoning the right way? or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the fact that MI is very, *very* rarely used in Python, usually only for mixins where the inheritance chain tends to be very short anyways.

Comment: And when it's useful, it's really useful. You get what you pay for; you pay for what you get.

Comment: I am interested to know why the MI is rarely used in Python?

Comment: Because Python is dynamically typed. There's no need to make a class belong to an explicit hierarchy in order to use it anywhere.

Comment: That makes sense... 
I happen to come across an article explaining the method resolution order in Python (http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), which clarified my understanding of how lookup of MI in Python works, and it seems that the complexity is not exponential as simply I thought...